# What is a good way to implement a function to make an array with inputted arguments?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to make a function that accepts any number of arguments and returns an array using those arguments as parameters. Here's the code example - I would like to do something like this, except it should work:

```
import numpy as np

def getgoodarray(*args):
    goodarray = np.round(np.arange(args)*10)
    return goodarray

B = getgoodarray(2, 3)  # this should make a 2d array, with two 1dimensional arrays, each of 3 elements
```

Do you have any idea on how this function could be implemented properly?

Comment: Please clarify your example. Why would np.arange output a 2x3 array?

Comment: Welcome to SO. PLease give more details and give an example of input and output you would like. This is not very clear as it is written.

Comment: what value in it ? zeros, ones, random ?

Comment: What's the error?  If it occurs in `np.arange` have you looked up its docs?  Or what else have you done to debug this - other than run to us crying for help? :)

Comment: `args` is a tuple, e.g. `(2,3)`.  `arange` wants 2 (or 3) numbers, not a tuple.  Also `arange` makes a 1d array.  It's does should make that clear.  It sounds like you have jumped into using `numpy` without reading much of the introductory material.

Answer (score 2):

Use any method that builds an array, fill with zeros, ones or random

```
def getgoodarray(*args):
    return np.ones(args)
    # return np.zeros(args)
    # return np.random.randint(0, 10, args)
```

```
x = getgoodarray(2, 3)
[[7 7 1]
 [8 2 5]]
```

```
x = getgoodarray(2, 2, 2, 3)
[[[[6 8 3]
   [7 0 0]]

  [[5 8 9]
   [6 8 5]]]


 [[[6 0 5]
   [8 7 0]]

  [[3 4 3]
   [0 2 4]]]]
```